# Issue with computed property not being updated for showing Sheet in Xcode 12 (worked before)

Tags: swiftui, ios14, computed-properties

This code has the following issue: The first click on any list item will show the sheet with "This is sheet 0" - meaning that @State property "var example: Int" is not updated as part of the button code (exit live preview and start it again, will reproduce the issue).

Any idea what is happening here !?

Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct testing2: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false
    @State var example: Int = 0
    var computedItem: String {
        "This is sheet \(example)"
    }

    var body: some View {
        List(0 ..< 5) { item in
            Button("List item: \(item)") {
                self.example = item
                showSheet.toggle()
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, content: {
            Text("\(computedItem)")
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @pawello2222 - this indeed helped to find the proper solution !

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether this would be the best answer, but this worked for me:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSheet = false
    @State var example: Int = 0
    @State var computedItem: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        List(0 ..< 5) { item in
            Button("List item: \(item)") {
                self.example = item
                self.computedItem = "This is sheet " + String(self.example)
                showSheet.toggle()
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            sheetView(computedItem: $computedItem)
        }
    }
}

struct sheetView: View {

    @Binding var computedItem: String

    var body: some View {
        Text(self.computedItem)
    }
}
```